# Initial product array not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with my code right now, I can't show the original list of products after I filter the products based on id. How can I show after I uncheck all the checkboxes the initial product list?

Service data :

```
productData() {
    return [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'x',
        price: 10,
        img:
          'x',
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'y',
        price: 20,
        img:
          'y',
      },

      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'z',
        price: 45,
        img:
          'z',
      },

      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'g',
        price: 81,
        img:
          'g',
      },

      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'b',
        price: 77,
        img:
          'b',
      },

      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'j',
        price: 101,
        img:
          'j',
      },

      {
        id: 1,
        name: 't',
        price: 90,
        img:
          't',
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'u',
        price: 222,
        img:
          'u',
      },

      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'r',
        price: 7,
        img:
          'r',
      },

      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'd',
        price: 56,
        img:
          'd',
      },

      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'a',
        price: 82,
        img:
          'a',
      },
    ];
  }
```

TS file

```
 checkboxArray: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'Producer1',
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'Producer2',
    },

    {
      id: 3,
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'Producer3',
    },

    {
      id: 4,
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'Producer4',
    },

    {
      id: 5,
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'Producer5',
    },

   
  ];
```

My function to filter the products from service based on what user check.
Its working on checked but if the user uncheck everything its not showing all the initial products. What can I do?

```
onChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.tempArray = this.arrays.filter(
        (e: any) => e.id == event.target.value
      );
      this.productArray = [];
      this.newArray.push(this.tempArray);
      // console.log(this.newArray);

      for (let i = 0; i < this.newArray.length; i++) {
        let firstArray = this.newArray[i];
        // console.log(firstArray);
        for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
          let obj = firstArray[i];
          this.productArray.push(obj);
          // console.log(this.productArray);
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.tempArray = this.productArray.filter(
        (e: any) => e.id != event.target.value
      );
      this.newArray = [];
      this.productArray = [];
      this.newArray.push(this.tempArray);
      // console.log(this.newArray);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.newArray.length; i++) {
        let firstArray = this.newArray[i];
        // console.log(firstArray);
        for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
          let obj = firstArray[i];
          this.productArray.push(obj);
          // console.log(this.productArray);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess the problem is that you're modifying the original array directly. You should have an array of static values(your values) and another array of items to show and when the user input something you filter the original array and do something like:

```js
const dataSource = [/* source array */];
const displayed = this.datasource.filter(ds => {/* logic */});
```

So anytime you want to modify the displayed items you always start from the datasource array(that remains unmodified).

EDIT: Also, you're using too many `let`. When declaring an array with `const` you can modify all the values inside of it except its reference

```js
const array = [];
array.push(1); // valid
array.pop(); //valid
array = [1, 2]; // invalid
```

Always choose const as it gives more strenght to your code;
Finally, i would like to give you a tip about loops, if your using a for loop just to get the current value of an array you can use the for...of loop, so that this:

```js
for(const item of array) {
 // logic in here
 console.log(item);
}
```

Is equal to this:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 // logic in here
 console.log(array[i]);
}
```